# Why does the UNIX sort utility ignore leading spaces without the option -b?

Tags: unix

[This is the rewrite of a similar question I asked backwards... Sorry for the confusion!]

I'm confused about leading s and the standard `sort` utility. Consider the contents of `myfile`:

```
a
 b
  a
```

Executing `sort -t : myfile` yields an unexpected result, at least to me:

```
a
  a
 b
```

Does that make sense? `<space>` should come either before `a-z` (as is the case in ASCII), or after. In the first case I would expect

```
  a
 b
a
```

while in the second case

```
a
 b
  a
```

Why, then, does `sort` seem to apply the `-b` option (ignore leading s) if when it wasn't included? In fact, to be safe I added the `-t` option in order to have exactly one field in each line. ([According to the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html), "A field comprises a maximal sequence of non-separating characters and, in the absence of option -t, any preceding field separator." `sort myfile` yields the same output, which is also unexpected.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [UNIX sort ignores whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6923464/3357935)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on the locale. With

```
LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 sort myfile
```

I get your unexpected result, and with

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort myfile
```

I get your expected result. Also see [bash sort unusual order. Problem with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493175/bash-sort-unusual-order-problem-with-spaces)

(I don't know *why* sort handles -b and -t like this.)

Comment: @Ernest: Enough of this! I removed the humility.

Comment: Thank you! As to how sort works under en_US.UTF-8, I can't understand it either... The [colletion chart](http://www.collation-charts.org/opensolaris/opensolaris.2008.05.en_US.UTF-8.html) for en_US.UTF-8 does not have a space between the A's and the B's...

Comment: Not only space. Try ".", "!", "?", "-", "(", ")", "+" and "~". They are also ignored in human (non-C) locales. Still not exactly like an implied -d option.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ sort -t : foo
a
    a
  b
$ env LC_ALL=C sort -t: foo
    a
  b
a
```

From the man page : 
*** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the  traditional sort order that uses native byte values.